Scrolling and typing lag with a 1-2 second delay
I have never had any serious problems with great Linux Ubuntu Operating System.
It's just that recently, after a fresh install of Linux Ubuntu 22.04, I stumbled upon this lag problem. I didn't have this problem before installation.
Right after the start-up of Linux Ubuntu OS there are no problems.
The problem starts approximately half an hour after start-up.
Then there is a 1-2 seconds lag when scrolling and typing in many applications.
When I scroll the mouse scroll just by 1 step then only after 1-2 seconds the contents get scrolled.
When scrolling mouse scroll by more steps then scrolling of contents will be simply delayed by 1-2 seconds.
This happens quite often in nautilus file browser, gedit text editor, and in CLI console.
Simultaneously, at the same time as scrolling lag, 1-2 second typing lag starts when typing keys on the keyboard.
There is a lag in the gedit Text editor especially noticeable when typing characters: Enter, backspace, delete, (ctrl+d), (ctrl+z).
Information of the system:
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:    jammy

uname -a
Linux pangratt-PC 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.9

Such a small thing, but can be so frustrating and excruciating.
I can provide more information if needed.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! If you have wire mouse, try another usb port.

Unfortunately this didn't help me, sorry :(

I'm seeing the same problem since an update/upgrade a couple of days ago. Just terminal, pluma (which is fork of gedit) and nautilus. Scrolling and typing is slow, and in particular, deleting multiple lines in pluma can be very slow, or even result in flickering in the text editor.

I am having serious keyboard problems since a couple of days ago, which is probably after I did an update. Typing into Geany is painfully slow, and gedit does not accept keyboard input at all.

Ok, I think that I have found a solution for this issue. If someone has better solution or knows more about this problem then I'm eager to hear other suggestions.
This issue was probably related to this recent update for Ubuntu 22.04 which might have had an accidental, small bug for Gnome mutter/libmutter packages.
Addressing Another Terminal Input Lag with Ubuntu 22.04
input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4
Surprisingly, they didn't mention mouse scrolling lags and typing lags in text editor in the above topics. Did anyone else experience this issue too? I did have some lags when using CLI console too, indeed.
After applying this solution mentioned by user Michael Gruberbauer from above topic all my problems were gone. So far, this issue hasn't reoccurred after several days now. So perhaps it's a permanent fix.

enable the proposed pocket on your system by going to the "Development Options" tab of the "Software & Updates" application and tick Pre-released updates (jammy-proposed)
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mutter/jammy-proposed 
sudo apt install libmutter-10-0/jammy-proposed
disable the proposed pocket again by unticking the option in (1.)
reboot the system

There will probably be updates/fixes soon to this Gnome mutter/libmutter packages included in general Ubuntu updates, without any need to do workarounds like above.

Did anyone else experience this issue too? For me, suddenly typing into Geany is slow, and gedit (Text Editor) doesn't accept keyboard input at all. I updated (sudo apt upgrade) a couple of days ago. It is driving me insane.

Yeah, I know that feel, bro. Sorry to hear that. This can be related to Gnome updates to version 42.9. You could try temporary solutions from these linked topics. They wrote that developers are working on this, according to Ubuntu Bugs Launchpad. There probably should be a general update for this issue soon.
